# GDB does not see symbols

Tags: ios, gdb

I have decrypted an app and ran `nm` command on the binary which gave me a very long list of symbols which I can also easily find in IDA PRO and Hopper. Yet when I am in GDB and run `info fun` on any of the symbols it tells me it cannot find it. When I dump `info fun` to a file none of the symbols match what I got from `nm`. Why is this? o.O

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using the file command on the decrypted app before attempting to run a debug session on the device.