# Get all .text (code) section symbols / symbol of local lambda object call operator in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

*Background: I'm trying to simplify my answer to the question [c++ - Calling a lambda function in GDB - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329925/calling-a-lambda-function-in-gdb).*

Consider this simple program

```cpp
int main(){
    auto a=[&](int x){return x+1;};
}
```

When it's compiled (for example to `a.out`), I can see

```sh
$ nm --demangle a.out  |grep lambda
000000000000113a t main::{lambda(int)#1}::operator()(int) const

$ nm  a.out  |grep 113a
000000000000113a t _ZZ4mainENKUliE_clEi
```

So there's a symbol `_ZZ4mainENKUliE_clEi` for the lambda `operator()` method in the text (code) section.

Given the exact name, I can print its value in gdb, and tab-completion also lists the symbol:

```
$ gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) print _ZZ4mainENKUliE_clEi
$1 = {int (const struct {...} * const, int)} 0x55555555513a <operator()(int) const>

(gdb) print 'main::{lambda(int)#1}::operator()(int) const'
$2 = {int (const struct {...} * const, int)} 0x55555555513a <operator()(int) const>
```

But how can I find the symbol **without using the external executable `nm` (inside gdb itself)**?
Answers using the Python API is preferred.

---

#### Failed attempts

As suggested in [c - Ask GDB to list all functions in a program - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680670/ask-gdb-to-list-all-functions-in-a-program):

```
(gdb) info functions .*lambda.*
All functions matching regular expression ".*lambda.*":

File /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/compatibility-thread-c++0x.cc:
        void std::once_flag::_Prepare_execution::_Prepare_execution<std::call_once<void (std::thread::*)(), std::
thread*>(std::once_flag&, void (std::thread::*&&)(), std::thread*&&)::{lambda()#1}>(void (std::thread::*&)())::{l
ambda()#1}::_FUN();
```

which is not the one I want, and

```
(gdb) info functions .*ZZ4.*
All functions matching regular expression ".*ZZ4.*":
```

doesn't match anything at all.

Also tried other things in [Debugging with GDB - Examining the Symbol Table](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_12.html),
`maintenance print symbols` doesn't have it either.

In [Symbols In Python (Debugging with GDB)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols-In-Python.html#Symbols-In-Python),
`gdb.lookup_global_symbol("_ZZ4mainENKUliE_clEi")` and `gdb.lookup_static_symbol("_ZZ4mainENKUliE_clEi")` both returns None.

`file ./a.out` in gdb does not help (suggested by [GDB does not see symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600287/gdb-does-not-see-symbols) )

Comment: Also note that before the program starts the relocate part did not execute, and address may display as `0x11dec` instead of `0x555555571dec`. See [GDB: why does memory mapping change after run? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208640/gdb-why-does-memory-mapping-change-after-run)

Comment: Looks like `maint print symbols` can be used, but usually the output is huge and it isn't even very straightforward how to use it.

Comment: Somewhat related but for variables [c - Get all global variables/local variables in gdb's python interface - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013252/get-all-global-variables-local-variables-in-gdbs-python-interface)

Answer (score 0):

This solution finds the address of the `.text` section by parsing the textual output of `info files`, then find the symbol correspond to each address by parsing the output of `info symbol` gdb command.

**Because it parses the textual output, in some special cases it might break**. If anyone have any better solution/improvement please suggest/post a new answer.

I took a look at https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Progspaces-In-Python.html#Progspaces-In-Python / https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Objfiles-In-Python.html but can't find any.

I can't use `block_for_pc`, explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916564/gdb-python-api-getting-symbol-name-from-address?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment124460829_47934269).

---

Run the Python code. The result is collected into the list `symbols`.

Read the comments in the code for more details how it works.

```py
# (setup measure time)
import time
start=time.time()

# step 1. Find the limit of `.text`. Store in (a, b).
import re
[[a, b]]=[
        (int(match[1], 16), int(match[2], 16))
        for line in gdb.execute("info files", to_string=True).splitlines()
        for match in [re.fullmatch(r"\s*(0x[0-9a-f]+) - (0x[0-9a-f]+) is \.text", line)]
        if match
        ]

# Step 2. Iterate through symbols.
symbols=[]
mismatch=0
i=b-1
while i>=a:
    line=gdb.execute("info symbol "+hex(i), to_string=True)
    if line=='No symbol matches '+hex(i)+'.\n':
        # There's no symbol here. Unfortunately I can't find any way to quickly skip through it.
        i-=1
        mismatch+=1
        continue
    # Determine the symbol and the offset.
    match=re.fullmatch(r"(.+) \+ (\d+) in section \.text of .*\n?", line)
    if match:
        symbol=match[1]
        offset=int(match[2])
    else:
        match=re.fullmatch(r"(.+) in section \.text of .*\n?", line)
        symbol=match[1]
        offset=0
    # collect the symbol into the list.
    i-=offset
    symbols.append((symbol, hex(i)))
    i-=1

# (report time taken)
print(time.time()-start, len(symbols), mismatch)
```

For a reasonably large executable, `nm` takes 0.042s, while the script takes 0.778s and report 5769 symbols and 44171 misses. (the misses takes most of the time)